# Count rows and columns that contains data from DataTable in C#.net

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, count

I've imported an excel file in my dataTable.
For some reason I need to count my total rows and columns number.
In my excel file, I've just used 3 rows giving 1,2,3 in 3 cells of Column A and Row 20,21,22.

Now the rows from 1 to 19 is not used, neither below 22, similarly, I didn't use Column B to the end of a typical excel file, just used A.

Thus, the correct answer would be Rows.Count = 3 and Columns.Count = 1.

Now, I want to count my used rows and columns of that DataTable. Please tell me how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not going to be a flag to tell you "is this row used flag " what you will need to do is determine what value will be in the rows that will not be used in this case 1-19, 22 you need to deside if checking one column in a row is sufficent or if you need to check all rows in the column to see if the row is used. Say I know that if MemberShipNumber is equal to null or "" then I know the whole row is not going to be used this is how I would do my check:

```
  foreach(DataRow dr in table)
  {

     if (string.String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["MembershipNumber"]))
     {
         Console.Write("This row is empty");
     } 
     else
     {
         Console.Write("This row is not empty there is more processing to do.");
     }
  }
```

Hope that helps